# How to format date in angular kendo Grid?

Tags: angular, date, kendo-grid

The incoming date format is as follows;2019-10-02T10:17:52.13, 2019-10-30T13:57:16.35 etc.

```
<kendo-grid-column
  field="CreatedTime"
  title="Date"
  filter="date"
  format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}">
</kendo-grid-column>
```

I couldn't format the date. How can I do? Thank you

Comment: Ho, the issue is that the parameter name are not nice enought . Thats a plain sql query. This is the real Sql query. And yes, it doesn't use the variable name as parameter names. But your question is not pointing in that direction you should [edit]. To ask why is auto generated or how to use custom variable name. you will get an answer on why it's impossible and how generated name make sure that 2 query with different variable name still get the same execution plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as below:

```
<kendo-grid-column
  field="CreatedTime"
  title="Date"
  filter="date"
  format="dd.MM.yyyy">
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52853903/how-to-format-date-in-angular-kendo-grid

Answer (score 0):

[As Telerik docs says:](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/ColumnComponent/#toc-format)

> The format that is applied to the value before it is displayed. Takes
>   the {0:format} form where format is a standard number format, a custom
>   number format, a standard date format, a custom date format or a
>   format object. For more information on the supported date and number
>   formats, refer to the [kendo-intl](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-intl/blob/develop/docs/index.md) documentation.

```
<kendo-grid>
   <kendo-grid-column field="FirstOrderedOn" [format]="{ date: 'short' }">
   </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```